# Adjust Image Lightning/Shadows using jQuery

Tags: jquery, image, shadow

I want to adjust image lighnting(highlight)/shadow(darkness) using slider in jquery ?
I have already tried [Pixastic](http://pixastic.com/lib/docs/actions/lighten/) but it's not working fine. It's just increasing value as I change slider value. Not retrives it's original image when change slider value.

Is there any other jquery tutorial to do it.

Here is my code which I have tried it with Pixastic.

```
<img id="image" src="pool.png" alt="your_image" />
<label for="blue">Highlight</label><input type="range" id="lighten_range" step=".05" min="-1" max="1" value="0" />

jQuery('#lighten_range').change(function(){

        var img = document.getElementById ('image');

        var lighten_val = parseFloat(jQuery('#lighten_range').val());
        Pixastic.process(img, "lighten", {amount:lighten_val});
    });
```

Can any one tell me image higlight / shadow can be managed with changing opacity of image using css.Are these same ?

Comment: Does the Pixastic demo work for you? It has precisely zero effect in in latest Opera (v12.15)

Comment: Correction - I'm wrong - you have to click the "Lighten" button after adjusting the slider. It works fine - just not a good demo.

Comment: @Beetroot-Beetroot Pixastic demo does not work on his site but I downloaded the js file and write down it's code then it just adds the value. I have tried it on chrome and mozila

Comment: @Beetroot-Beetroot Demo is not working I think on Publisher site.Slider is not working

Comment: Abdul, agreed, the thing doesn't work properly. We have to suspect it's the "Lighten" code itself, not just the demo. You need to search for a better plugin.

Comment: @Beetroot-Beetroot I am searching plugin but not able to find any one. :(

Comment: You could try [Pixidou](http://www.verious.com/code/pixidou-an-open-source-ajax-image-editor-php-and-yui-based/), which is YUI-based, not jQuery, and involves a server (PHP5.2+ and GD2).

Comment: @Beetroot-Beetroot It does not have Highlight option...

Comment: It allows "adjust brightness". Is that not what you want?

Comment: @Beetroot-Beetroot no I am looking for lightening (highlighting) image like http://www.picmonkey.com/

Answer (score 1):

For everyone else who's trying to build a slider-tool for editing photos.

HTML example for a single slider id defines the method and name the attribute:

```
<label>Sharpen</label>
<input id="sharpen" name="amount" type="range" value="0" min="0" max="50" onchange="pe_Edit()"><br>
<br><br><hr><br>
<img src="myimg.jpg" id="pe_photo">
```

JS:

```
        function pe_Edit() {
        //define photo id
        var id = '#pe_photo';
        var src = $(id).attr('src');
        Pixastic.revert(document.getElementById('pe_photo'));

        $( "input" ).each(function( index ) {
            var value = $(this).val()/100;
            var action = $(this).attr('id');
            var effect = $(this).attr('name');
            var pix_cmd = jQuery.parseJSON( '{ "'+effect+'":"'+value+'" }' );
            $(id).pixastic(action, pix_cmd);
        });
    }
```